# How to deploy a laravel5 & vuejs application?

Tags: laravel, deployment, vue.js

i have a laravel 5 & vuejs application on my local server (vue js that comes with laravel). And now i want to deploy this application on real server like "000webhost.com" to test.
Laravel works fine, but Vue doesn't, I get some unexpected behaviors like blank page when assigning the id="app" to the parent element, and when i remove the id="app" the page appears and works correctly but Vue doesn't.

This is my project structure:
[project structure](http://www13.0zz0.com/2018/01/26/17/653174993.jpg)

When uploading,, I upload the whole project without "node_modules" directory (that comes with npm install) Could this be the reason ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` to create your resource bundle with the javascript and other assets. You technically don't need node_modules, so long as you build the projects on another machine and upload all that to your hosted server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,, do you mean run "npm run prod" on my local project then upload it ??

Comment: Yep, run `npm run prod` on your local project and then upload to your server.

Comment: I am getting trouble during deployment `laravel+vue`. Would you help me please.... - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991720/deploy-laravelvuejs-application